# Rename with pattern

Tags: regex, perl, rename

I have a lot of files looking like this:

```
"THIS IS my file.txt"
"THIS IS My file.txt"
"THIS IS m file.txt"
"THIS IS M file.txt"
```

So basically, if I try to describe it, the filename is composed of two parts, one in upper case, the other in lower case (though the first letter of the second part can be in upper case too). Words can be composed of one single char. When there's a choice, a single character word in upper case in considered to be of the first part.

I'd like to extract the first part of the filename, composed of upper case words, put them to lowercase (with just the first letter as uppercase), and seperate it from the rest with an hyphen.

So the result I'm expecting is:

```
"This Is - my file.txt"
"This Is - My file.txt"
"This Is - m file.txt"
"This Is M - file.txt"
```

What I have so far is:

```
rename 's/^(([A-Z]{2,}| )+)(.*)/\u\L$1\E - $3/g' *
```

But there are quite a few problems with it (one letter upper case words don't match, and only the first word is capitalized).

Comment: That's not how the Perl `rename` function works.  According to the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) rename takes two arguments, _oldname_,_newname_.  You have two problems to solve: 1) figure out where the split should occur; 2) change case and insert hyphen. I suggest you tackle them separately to begin with.

Comment: @JimGarrison I suspect he is talking about the `rename` command line tool in linux.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm not using the rename function of perl, but the rename utility available in linux. It uses perl regex however, according to its man page. Yes my first problem is how to separate them using regex pattern matching, I have failed to do so for one letter words as I said above.

Comment: What would you want for `THIS is my file.txt`; presumably `This - is my file.txt`?  So there need not be two capitalized words — or is that a requirement.

Comment: you're right. The result should be This - is my file.txt. Only the capitalized words are to be put to lowercase (except for the first character). The number of words are irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I think the regex you're looking for would be:

```
s/^((?:[A-Z]+ )+)/(join " ", map ucfirst, split " ", lc $1) . " - "/e
```

I tested it like this:

```
$ perl -pe 's/^((?:[A-Z]+ )+)/(join " ", map ucfirst, split " ", lc $1) . " - "/e' <<eoq
THIS IS my file.txt
THIS IS My file.txt
THIS IS m file.txt
THIS IS M file.txt
eoq
```

Here's the output:

```
This Is - my file.txt
This Is - My file.txt
This Is - m file.txt
This Is M - file.txt
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work ! Care to explain a bit ? I didn't know I could do functions and such in regex...

Comment: The /e flag at the end of the regex says the replacement value is a perl expression that should be evaled, rather than just interpolated.

Comment: (thanks, but I meant explain the content of the regex). I don't know what "?:, join, map, ucfirst, split, lc, e" mean.

Comment: The ?: just tells the regex engine not to capture the value for that group, it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: join, map, ucfirst, split, and lc are Perl functions, see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#Perl-Functions-by-Category

Comment: But what about this unusual syntax, with commas in between the functions ? I don't know anything about perl, I just have some basic knowledge about regular expressions, and I don't understand this syntax. Can you please explain in a bit more details what this does?

Comment: @Simhor you can use join without brackets, try: `perl -pe 'print join "", "123", "abc"'` 
+1 for the nice answer@kdkeck